# Script Output In Polybar Network Module?

Tags: terminal, window-manager, interface, toolbar, lemonbar

In standard module we has:

```ini
[module/wlan]
type = internal/network
interface-type = wireless
interval = 5
format-connected = <label-connected>
format-disconnected = <label-disconnected>
label-disconnected = disconnected
label-connected = %local_ip%
```

How can I concat a script output to this property (`label-connected`)? e.g.:

```ini
label-connected = %local_ip% $(my-script)
```